# zipping lists in R

Tags: r, plyr, lapply

As a guideline I prefer apply functions on elements of a list using lapply or *ply (from plyr) rather than explicitly iterating through them. However, this works well when I have to process one list at a time. When the function takes multiple arguments, I usually do a cycle.

I was wondering if it's possible to have a cleaner construct, still functional in nature. One possible approach could be to define a function similar to Python, zip(x,y), which takes the input lists, and returns a list, whose i-th element is list(x, y), and then apply the function to this list. But my question is whether I am using the cleanest approach or not. I am not worried about performance optimization, but rather clarity/elegance.

Below is the naive example.

```
        A <- as.list(0:9)
        B <- as.list(0:9)
        f <- function(x, y) x^2+y

        OUT <- list()
        for (n in 1:10) OUT[[n]] <- f(A[[n]], B[[n]])
        OUT
        [[1]]
        [1] 0

        [[2]]
        [1] 2

        ...
```

And here is the zipped example (which could be extended to arbitrary arguments):

```
zip <- function(x, y){
    stopifnot(length(x)==length(y))
    z <- list()
    for (i in seq_along(x)){
        z[[i]] <- list(x[[i]], y[[i]]) 
    }
    z
}
E <- zip(A, B)

lapply(E, function(x) f(x[[1]], x[[2]]))

[[1]]
[1] 0

[[2]]
[1] 2

 ...
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I think you're looking for `mapply`:

```
   ‘mapply’ is a multivariate version of ‘sapply’.  ‘mapply’ applies
     ‘FUN’ to the first elements of each ...  argument, the second
     elements, the third elements, and so on.  Arguments are recycled
     if necessary.
```

For your example, use `mapply(f, A, B)`

Comment: There is also `plyr` family of `m*ply` functions.

Comment: And Map which is a thin wrapper around mapply

Answer (score 4):

I came across a similar problem today. And after learning the usage of the func `mapply`, I know how to solve it now.

`mapply` is so cool!!

Here is an examples:

```
en = c("cattle", "chicken", "pig")
zh = c("牛",      "鸡",      "猪")

dict <- new.env(hash = TRUE)
Add <- function(key, val) dict[[key]] <- val

mapply(Add, en, zh)
##  cattle chicken     pig 
##    "牛"    "鸡"    "猪"
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you could do this with what I call an 'implicit loop' (this name does not hit it fully, but whatever), taking into account that you can loop over vectors within `*apply`:

```
OUT <- lapply(1:10, function(x) (A[[x]]^2 + B[[x]]))
```

or

```
OUT <- lapply(1:10, function(x) f(A[[x]], B[[x]]))
```

Note that you then could also use `vapply` (or 'sapply`) for output managing (i.e. if you don't want a list).

(by the way, I am not getting what you want with the `zip` function, so I am sorry, if I missed your point.)